# How To Split Authors with REGEX to object or array C#?

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I am working on a software which reads a .txt file content and writes that content into ms word's Sources.xml.

I want to split a text to object or array (doesn't matter).

The point is that if a part of sentence contains one (or more) capitalized letter and a dot (.) it is an author. If the sentence contains multiple author them are split by comma beforehand.

**EXAMPLE INPUT**

> W.M.P. van der Aalst K. Van Hee, Workflow Management: Models, Methods, and Systems (MIT Press, Cambridge, 2004) 
>   A. Shtub, R. Karni, ERP: The Dynamics of Supply Chain and Process Management (Springer,Berlin, 2010)

**First Input's Output should be like this:** W.M.P. van der Aalst K. Van Hee

**Secons Input's Output should be like this:** A. Shtub and R. Karni **(they can be an array or object it doesn't matter but I must work with them one by one)**

EXAMPLE CODE

```js
references[0] = "A. Shtub, R. Karni, ERP: The Dynamics of Supply Chain and Process Management (Springer,Berlin, 2010)"

var a = Regex.Split(references[0], @"([A-Z][.])*\s\w*[,]").ToList();

//Output should be like:
//            a[0] = A. Shtub
//            a[1] = R. Karni
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always just split the entire string by commas to make it easier to work with:

```
var a = (from words in references[1].Split(',')
         where !words.Any(ch => char.IsNumber(ch)) && Regex.IsMatch(words, "([A-Z][.])+") && !Regex.IsMatch(words, "[a-zA-Z]{2,}[.]")
         select words.Trim()).ToList(); // .ToList() not required here if not needed

foreach (string str in a)
{
  Console.WriteLine(str);
  // references[0] output:
  // W.M.P. van der Aalst K. Van Hee

  // references[1] output:
  // A. Shtub
  // R. Karni
}
```

`Regex.IsMatch(words, "([A-Z][.])+")` will make sure the pattern is actually there.

`!Regex.IsMatch(words, "[a-zA-Z]{2,}[.]")` will exclude any with 2 or more letters preceding the dot.

Comment: There is a problem. Author name contains just one capitalized letter and a dot. For example:  "A. Shtub" or "W.M.P. van der Aalst K. Van Hee" are authors but "2nd. Edition" is not an author.

Comment: @EdizNezir you're right, added a clause to exclude any numerical characters as well.

Comment: Actually numerical characters are not enough. For example "edn." is still a problem for me. The query must take "A.B.C." or "A." formats, not "ABC." or "abc."  One letter and dot.

Comment: @EdizNezir I misunderstood sorry, made another edit and that's hopefully what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

A broad match might be to match an uppercase char followed by a digit and use a negated character class matching any char except a comma.

```
\b[A-Z]\.[^,]+
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5bA-Z%5d%5c.%5b%5e%2c%5d%2b&i=W.M.P.+van+der+Aalst+K.+Van+Hee%2c+Workflow+Management%3a+Models%2c+Methods%2c+and+Systems+%28MIT+Press%2c+Cambridge%2c+2004%29+%0d%0a%0d%0aA.+Shtub%2c+R.+Karni%2c+ERP%3a+The+Dynamics+of+Supply+Chain+and+Process+Management+%28Springer%2cBerlin%2c+2010%29)

A bit more specific pattern might be matching 1+ times an uppercase char followed by a comma and then use repeated groups matching a space followed by wordhcharacters and an optional dot. At the end use a positive lookahead to assert a comma.

```
\b(?:[A-Z]\.)+(?: \w+\.?)* \w+(?=,)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cb%5bA-Z%5d%5c.%29%2b%28%3f%3a+%5cw%2b%5c.%3f%29*+%5cw%2b%28%3f%3d%2c%29&i=W.M.P.+van+der+Aalst+K.+Van+Hee%2c+Workflow+Management%3a+Models%2c+Methods%2c+and+Systems+%28MIT+Press%2c+Cambridge%2c+2004%29+%0d%0a%0d%0aA.+Shtub%2c+R.+Karni%2c+ERP%3a+The+Dynamics+of+Supply+Chain+and+Process+Management+%28Springer%2cBerlin%2c+2010%29) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/pmTDAV)

For example

```
string pattern = @"\b(?:[A-Z]\.)+(?: \w+\.?)* \w+(?=,)";
string input = @"W.M.P. van der Aalst K. Van Hee, Workflow Management: Models, Methods, and Systems (MIT Press, Cambridge, 2004) 
A. Shtub, R. Karni, ERP: The Dynamics of Supply Chain and Process Management (Springer,Berlin, 2010)";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Output

```
W.M.P. van der Aalst K. Van Hee
A. Shtub
R. Karni
```